# (AC circuits) Why do I need to use the superposition theorem when dealing with two or more different sources with different frequencies?

Tags: circuit-analysis, ac, source, superposition

Consider:

[image]

I know that the elements would have different impedances under different frequencies, but I can’t really visualize it.
Also, is there another way to analyze the circuit (other than superposition)?

This question is specific to AC steady state analysis.

Comment: There are different ways to analyze circuits. And there are different goals for analysis. And there are many different ways our brains prefer to process information -- what "sings in our mind like a melody" is quite different for one person vs another. So the better choices of thinking tools aren't universal, either. There's no one-size-fits-all. This also means that different people bring different tools to the party. For the super-geniuses, though, the tools they possess are quite a bit more similar to each other because of how they jointly value only those tools with great power and reach.

Comment: Provide a schematic to use as an example, so that others have a clearer idea of what you are on about here. Then specify some particular analysis goals you have in mind. And then ask for an analysis done two-ways to get the same result. Perhaps something useful can come of that.

Comment: I added a circuit as an example (I want to find i0 in steady state)

Comment: Can you [crop the image](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cropping_(image)), please? You can [edit (change)](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/posts/605409/edit) your question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only need to use superposition if you are doing things in the frequency domain. Think about the equations you use for circuit elements in the frequency domain.

- Inductors are \$Z_L = j\omega L\$
- Capacitors are \$Z_C = \frac{1}{j\omega C}\$
- Sinusoidal current and voltage sources are \$M\angle \theta\$

Think about what the \$\omega\$ is those equations. It's just one frequency. In other words a sine wave. Just one. One \$\omega\$ variable can't describe more than one sine wave. And the phasor form of the voltage source removes the frequency altogether because it assumes only one frequency which is taken into account elsewhere and must be the same everywhere else.

So if you analyze in the frequency domain then you must separate out each constituent frequencies into its own circuit then add them all up at the end via superposition.

If you do it in the time domain you don't need superposition. You can use it, but you don't strictly need it because then the equations for those circuit elements are:

- \$I_c = C\frac{dV}{dT}\$ for capacitors
- \$V_L = L\frac{di}{dT}\$ for inductors
- \$Mcos(\omega t + \theta)\$ for sinusoidal voltage and current sources

Those time domain equations take into account the entire picture not by looking at frequencies (which are only mathematically rigorous when applied to individual sine waves), but look at rates of change which is able to analyze things from moment to moment completely ignoring the concept of frequency. If you think hard enough about it doesn't causal make sense for a real component to *know* the frequency because to know the frequency of something means that means it must know that it is a sine wave into the future and what that sine wave is. Obviously, the circuit elements can't see the future but it can see the rate of change right now.

The catch is that real waveforms are arbitrary so you almost never have analytical equations to describe them with for use in the time domain. But sinusoidal equations are analytical and via Fourier you can turn any arbitrary waveform into frequencies to work with in the frequency domain. Though I suppose you could just use it in the time domain as a massive sum of cosines (which actually is superposition, but you just aren't separating the circuits out into different versions like in the frequency domain). From that hopefully you can see it actually all is the same thing and elegant, in concept at least. The math can look messy.

Also solving time domain equations containing terms with those integrals and derivatives means differential equations. Trickier than frequency domain. That's the other catch of the time domain.